# network geofencing without an app for android and ios

Tags: geolocation, core-location, geofencing, android-geofence, location-based-service

I want to do a little bit geofence advertising but I want people to receive my notifications regardless of weather they have my app or not.
so just with their location on, they are gonna be able to receive the advertising.

is this even possible? if yes, can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible.

1. You cannot get user-location unless user installs your app which has permission to access to user-location.
2. You cannot send push notifications, unless user installs your app which has permission to receive push notification.

Comment: Not True Zee. You can use push notifications so long as the user has an app installed that allows User location and has permissions to receive push notifications. It does not necessarily need to be your app. It does have to be a publisher however that allows advertisers to access through a DSP.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your input, since this platform is for programming related questions, so my answer was within programming context. However, I would agree with you on the possibility of using service (Demand-side platform A.K.A DSP) as a solution to this scenario.